# RESTful API Returning Proper Errors

Tags: python, api, rest

I am building a RESTful API for my very first time as a class project, but what is confusing me is error handling for certain scenarios.

When a client request:

```
https://localhost:8080/api/v1/user/<username>
```

I check the *username* variable for numerous things such as:

- If the username is empty or "blank"
- If the username is alphanumerical
- If the length of the username is too short or too long

So, my code looks like this at the moment, (It's in Python, but that is irrelevant):

```
# We just grabbed the username variable

# if the username is blank, return 404
if not username:
    abort(404)
# if the username is not alphanumerical, return 404
if not alias.isalnum():
    abort(404)
# if the username length is less than 4 or greater than 25, return 404
if len(alias) < 4 or len(alias) > 25:
    abort(404)
```

Returning 404 errors with no means of error "identification" seems wrong to me.

Should I be returning 404 error codes displaying what went wrong (e.g. "The username given was not alphanumerical")?

Should I be returning a different HTTP status code other than 404?

I am incredibly confused!

Comment: make your 404 page (or even better a 500 page) a template which can accept custom message to display

Comment: @NikosM. I have thought about this (well, not about the returning 500 error part), but my worry is if whether or not this is good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many types of HTTP status code, your REST API should return the correct code for the scenario.

Here is a good resource:
http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Also, respond with a JSON payload that offers help to the developer. Something simple like this:

```
{
    “kind”: “error#404”,
    “message”: string, // Give a short message about error
    “more-info”: string // Provide more detailed error report
}
```

Hope that helps.